# Join Existing table with Temp Table

Tags: sql

I pass year value to input parameter(@Year) of my proc

```
    SELECT @Year [Year]
    , t.Name AS [Town]
    , COUNT(r.Id) AS [PropertyCount]
    , CASE
        WHEN @Year - [Age] < 11 THEN '1-10'
        WHEN @Year - [Age] BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS [AgeRange]
    FROM Properties  r 
    JOIN Towns t
        ON t.Id  = r.TownId
     WHERE t.Id = @TownId
    GROUP BY
      t.Name,
    CASE
        WHEN @Year - [Age] < 11 THEN '1-10'
        WHEN @Year - [Age] BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END
```

I want to get result set for next 4 years. So I created temp table as below.

```
    DECLARE @tempTable table(YearValue SMALLINT)
    INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES (@Year )
    INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES (@Year + 1)
    INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES (@Year + 2)
    INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES (@Year + 3)
```

But How can I join temp table with other query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query. Uses a simple `JOIN` on `@temptable`

```
SELECT tt.YearValue [Year]
    , t.Name AS [Town]
    , COUNT(r.Id) AS [PropertyCount]
    , CASE
        WHEN tt.YearValue - [Age] < 11 THEN '1-10'
        WHEN tt.YearValue - [Age] BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS [AgeRange]

FROM 
@tempTable tt LEFT JOIN 
Properties  r 
     JOIN Towns t
        ON t.Id  = r.TownId
     WHERE t.Id = @TownId
    GROUP BY
      t.Name,
    CASE
        WHEN tt.YearValue - [Age] < 11 THEN '1-10'
        WHEN tt.YearValue - [Age] BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a CROSS JOIN or an INNER JOIN with condition 1 = 1. You really probably don't need a temp table either. It does appear you're using SQL Server so I'm kind of assuming that even though the query is readily adaptable to other platforms.

```
SELECT
    yr AS "Year", t.Name AS Town, COUNT(r.Id) AS PropertyCount,
    CASE
        WHEN yr - Age < 11 THEN '1-10'
        WHEN yr - Age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS AgeRange
FROM
    Properties as r INNER JOIN Towns as t ON t.Id  = r.TownId
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT @Year as yr UNION ALL Select @Year + 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT @Year + 2   UNION ALL SELECT @Year + 3
    ) AS y ON 1 = 1 /* lots of variations on syntax here depending on your flavor of SQL */
WHERE t.Id = @TownId
GROUP BY
    yr,
    t.Name,
    CASE
        WHEN yr - Age < 11 THEN '1-10'
        WHEN yr - Age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END
```